# Separar arrays em colunas numa tabela html

Tags: php, mysql, array, table

Eu queria separar a minha array por colunas numa tabela.
Quando insiro os registos fica com uma ',', mas quando tiro a virgula fica com um erro de Array to string conversion. Podiam me ajudar?

Como eu queria que ficasse a tabela:

### Data|Nome|Valor

### 2020-01-02|a|1.00€

### 2020-01-02|b|1.00€

### Valor total| 2.00€

Como está:
[image: Descrição]

Está aqui o meu código:

```
<table style="width: 50%;" border='0' id="table" name="table">
   <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Data</th>
        <th width="25%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Nome do custo</th>
        <th width="8%" align='center' bgcolor='#baba84'>Valor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$total_valor = 0;
while($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
{

    echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td align="left" bgcolor="white">'.$registo['data'].'</td>';
        echo'<td bgcolor="white">'. $registo['nome_custo'].'</td>';
    if($registo['valor']>=$registo['valor'].".00"){
        $valor=$registo['valor'].".00";
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$valor."€</td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor=$valor' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>");
    }
    else{
        echo "<td align='left' bgcolor='white'>".$registo['valor']."€></td>";
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='alterar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}&data={$registo['data']}&nome={$registo['nome_custo']}&valor={$registo['valor']}' class='button2'>Ver</a></td>");
        print ("<td bgcolor='white' width='1%'><a href='eliminar_custos.php?num={$registo['num']}' class='button2'>Eliminar</a></td>"); 

    }
    $total_valor += $registo['valor'];
}

?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td align='left' colspan='2' bgcolor='#baba84'><b>Valor Total</b></td>
        <td align='left' bgcolor='white'><?php echo number_format($total_valor, 2, '.', '.')."€"; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Teria que entender o motivo de você armazenar os dados do "Nome do Custo" desta forma "a,b", parece algum erro de modelagem, mudando o insert para individualizar o nome do custo você não teria este problema.

Uma solução alternativa:

```
<?php
$newArray = [];
while($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
{
    $arrayNomeDoCusto = explode(',' $registro['nome_custo']);
    foreach($arrayNomeDoCusto as $key => $value)
    {
       $newArray[$key] = $registo;
       $newArray[$key]['nome_custo'] = $value;
    }

}
```

$newArray pode ser percorrido agora com sua individualidade.